# Highmaps mapbubble legend moves when zooming in the map

Tags: javascript, highcharts, legend

I use Highmaps to display bubbles on a mapline. Everything works well but if I display in the legend the color axis and the size of bubbles, there is a strange behavior when I zoom in the map.
The legend moves up on the first zoom level.

you can see the effect on the sample here : https://jsfiddle.net/vegaelce/L3ghxpqw/

Click on "+" or use the mouse wheel to zoom in and observe the legend is moving up.

The legend is defined as

```
legend: {           
enabled: true,
shadow: true,       
backgroundColor: "#efefef",         
itemMarginBottom: 15,
bubbleLegend: {             
enabled: true,          
}},
```

I absolutely need the legend to be fixed. How can I achieve this please ?

Comment: This is the bug. I reported it at Highcharts GitHub issue tracker. You can follow it here for any updates or workarounds: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/20710